# Как записывать/читать integer в файле - android

Tags: java, android, файлы

Как записывать/читать переменную integer в файл из external storage

Comment: просто сохраняете как бинарный файл. Свой код покажите, если не работает исправим

Answer (score 4):

```
Integer myInteger = Integer.valueOf(10);

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.dat");

// запись
DataOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    out.writeInt(myInteger.intValue());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// чтение
DataInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    Integer myReadInt = Integer.valueOf(in.readInt());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Также необходимы пермишны:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Перед записью/чтением лучше проверить доступность хранилища:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```